# How to send data using JSONP from localhost to domain.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to send data as `json` from `localhost` to a website `domain.com` and I see that `jquery` can't send it when using `cross-domains`;

Then I read about `jsonp` and now I don't know how to write the code;

Somehow I need to replace the code from the `news` function with a `jsonp` call;

```
<script>
    function news(data) {
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'http://domain.com/index.php/api/news',
            'data': {'data': data},
            'success': function(data) {
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
    function unique(data) {
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'http://localhost/fb-group/index.php/api/unique',
            'data': {'data': data},
            'success': function(data) {
                if (data && (data.status === 1) && data.news) {
                    news(data.news);
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
    access_token = 'token';
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'https://graph.facebook.com/453240374771082?fields=feed&method=GET&format=json&suppress_http_code=1&access_token=' + access_token,
        'data': '',
        'success': function(data) {
            if (data && data.feed && data.feed.data) {
                allData = data.feed.data;
                $.each(allData, function(index, value) {
                    unique(value);
                });
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
</script>
```

is this ok on the server side?

this is how i catch , parse and save the date received thru ajax call

```
    public function actionNews() {
        $data = json_encode($_GET['data']);
        $data_decoded = json_decode($data);
//        print_r($data_decoded);
        $model_feedM = new FeedMLive();
        $model_feedM->data_id = $data_decoded->id;
        $model_feedM->data_from_name = $data_decoded->from->name;
        $model_feedM->data_from_id = $data_decoded->from->id;
        $model_feedM->data_to_data_name = $data_decoded->to->data[0]->name;
        $model_feedM->data_to_data_id = $data_decoded->to->data[0]->id;
        $model_feedM->data_message = strlen($data_decoded->message) > 0 ? $data_decoded->message : 'unknown';
        $model_feedM->data_picture = isset($data_decoded->picture) ? $data_decoded->picture : 'unknown';
        $model_feedM->data_link = isset($data_decoded->link) ? $data_decoded->link : 'unknown';
        $model_feedM->views = 0;
        $model_feedM->created = time();
        $model_feedM->status = FeedM::ACTIVE;
        if ($model_feedM->validate() && $model_feedM->save())
            echo '{"status_live":"1"}';
        else
            echo '{"status_live":"0"}';
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Just change `dataType: 'json'` to `dataType: 'jsonp'`? Note that JSONP is just adding a `script` element to the DOM, so your data will be sent via the `data` keyword in the query string. Of course the server must also read the value from the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function news(data) {
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'http://domain.com/index.php/api/news?callback=?',
        'data': {'data': data},
        'success': function(data) {
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
function unique(data) {
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'http://localhost/fb-group/index.php/api/unique?callback=?',
        'data': {'data': data},
        'success': function(data) {
            if (data && (data.status === 1) && data.news) {
                news(data.news);
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
access_token = 'token';
$.ajax({
    'url': 'https://graph.facebook.com/453240374771082?fields=feed&method=GET&format=json&suppress_http_code=1&access_token=' + access_token+'&callback=?',
    'data': '',
    'success': function(data) {
        if (data && data.feed && data.feed.data) {
            allData = data.feed.data;
            $.each(allData, function(index, value) {
                unique(value);
            });
        }
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Server gets 'callback' param and return data include value of 'callback' param,
This is cross-domains by jquery!

Comment: i am checking, pls wait

Comment: what?  return nothing?

Comment: Server Data Format：echo $_REQUERT["callback"].'('.json_encode(data).')';