# Javascript not referencing local json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, dart

I cannot seem to be able to get my variable to reference the local json file instead of the current remote json file.  I want to be able to set the Javascript to read the local test.json file instead of the remote resturl url.  I want to change the current resturl variable to the commented resturl below it.  Please let me know if you need more information.  The scripts are based off of: https://github.com/kenklin/aws-price-comparison-chart

```
function update() {
// Construct REST URL
 var resturl = "http://p1software-eb1.elasticbeanstalk.com/awsec2offering/api"
  + "/" + d3.select("#availabilityZone").node().value // us-east-1a
  + "/" + d3.select("#productDescription").node().value // linux
  + "/" + d3.select("#offeringType").node().value   // heavy
  + "/" + d3.select("#instanceType1").node().value    // t1.micro
  + "," + d3.select("#instanceType2").node().value;   // m1.small

// resturl = "test.json"
// resturl = "http://localhost:8080/awsec2offering/awsec2offering/api/us-east-1a/linux/heavy/t1.micro,m1.small."
d3.json(resturl, function(error, json) {
  data = json.ec2offerings;

  // Assign colors to each unique name. 
  var color = d3.scale.category10();
  color.domain(data.map(function(p) { return createUniqueName(p); }));

  // Coerce the data to numbers.
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.month = +d.month;
  });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No.  When I change the variable I do however get: Breaking on exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ec2offerings' of undefined

Comment: Does `error` contain anything?

Comment: No.  I am basing my example off of: https://github.com/kenklin/aws-price-comparison-chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONP with callback parameter to get cross-domain scripting

[How to send data using JSONP from localhost to domain.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568395/how-to-send-data-using-jsonp-from-localhost-to-domain-com)

Comment: I'm unsure of what to do there.  I have no experience with JSONP.  Could you possibly provide a code-based answer?

Comment: Assuming that your code is running off a server, example.com, and you want localhost, then your localhost url should be: `http://localhost:8080/test.json?callback=?`   This might also work, but unlikely: `file:///path/to/file/test.json?callback=?`

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd write that because http://localhost:8080/test.json did not seem to work.  It's in the same directory.

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit my answer because I keep hitting `enter` on accident.

Comment: Here is another reference URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp

Comment: It's just running locally on my machine for now. Any ideas for running it off of your own machine? What's the last callback=? for too?