# Send data using POST to JSONP request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post, jsonp

**Summary :**

Want to send data to another domain using POST method to JSONP.

**Code :**

```js
$http.jsonp($scope.baseApiUrl+'QueryBuilder/getData?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.success = true;
    console.log(data);
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.error = true;
});
```

Its working fine. But I have a lot of data that I need to send to the service, cross domain, and it is too large to send via the querystring. So I want to send it as JSON.

```json
data: {
    "dbName":"test",
    "tables":["city","persons"],
    "filters":["city_id='Hyd'"]
}
```

**Findings :**

[How to make a jsonp POST request that specifies contentType with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860111/how-to-make-a-jsonp-post-request-that-specifies-contenttype-with-jquery)
[Unable to post data using JSONP on Cross Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933977/unable-to-post-data-using-jsonp-on-cross-domain)
[How to send data using JSONP from localhost to domain.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568395/how-to-send-data-using-jsonp-from-localhost-to-domain-com)
[Using PUT/POST/DELETE with JSONP and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345493/using-put-post-delete-with-jsonp-and-jquery)

Every post shows that it is not possible.so is there any alternate way to do this ?

**Question :**

Is it possible to post data to JSONP? Or does all data have to be passed in the querystring as a GET request?

Any immediate help will be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Also see: [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745). And here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/muyegetogu/edit?js,output) based on that question which uses an iframe to post json cross-domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to post data to JSONP?

No, it isn't.

JSONP works by adding a `<script>` element that *gets* data from its `src` (the data is embedded in a JavaScript program). You can't make a POST request to load a JavaScript program.

> Or does all data have to be passed in the querystring as a GET request?

Yes

---

JSONP is a dirty hack to get around the Same Origin Policy.

CORS was introduced as standard way to get around the Same Origin Policy that is much, much more flexible. You can make POST requests with XMLHttpRequest if authorised by CORS. Use CORS instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is there any alternate way to do that ?

Comment: @RohitJindal — CORS is the alternative way.

Comment: By using CORS i am able to send data as POST without getting the cross-origin issue.?

Comment: @RohitJindal — From the answer: "You can make POST requests with XMLHttpRequest if authorised by CORS"